# Vulkan: vkCmdPipelineBarrier for data coherence

Tags: c++, vulkan, barrier

My question has 2 parts:

1. What is the difference between memory being available / being visible?
2. Im learning Vulkan from this tutorial (https://vulkan-tutorial.com) and currently sneaking around for a different approach to upload uniform data (simple model/view/projection matrices) to a device local memory. The matrices are used in the vertex shader.

   In the tutorial the matrices get updated and are copied to a staging buffer (`vkMapMemory` etc.) and are copied afterwards to the final device local buffer by creating a command buffer, recording `vkCmdCopy`, submiting it and destroying the buffer. I try to do the last step within the obligatory command buffers for drawing.

   While the tutorial way leads to a fluent animation, my experiment misses this feature. I tried to install 2 bufferBarriers to ensure that the copies are done (which seems to be problem), but that didn't help. The resources are properly created and bound - that's working fine.

   ```
   //update uniform buffer and copy it to the staging buffer
   //(called every frame)
   Tools::UniformBufferObject ubo;
   //set the matrices
   void* data;
   data = device.mapMemory( uniformStagingMemory, 0, sizeof( ubo ), (vk::MemoryMapFlagBits) 0 );
     memcpy( data, &ubo, sizeof( ubo ));
   device.unmapMemory( uniformStagingMemory );


   //once: create a command buffer for each framebuffer of the swapchain
   //queueFamily struct members set properly
   //1st barrier: make transfer from host memory to staging buffer available / visible
   vk::BufferMemoryBarrier bufMemBarrierStaging;
   bufMemBarrierStaging.srcAccessMask = vk::AccessFlagBits::eHostWrite;
   bufMemBarrierStaging.dstAccessMask = vk::AccessFlagBits::eTransferRead;
   bufMemBarrierStaging.buffer = uniformStagingBuffer;
   bufMemBarrierStaging.offset = 0;
   bufMemBarrierStaging.size = sizeof( Tools::UniformBufferObject );

   //2nd barrier: make transfer from staging buffer to device local buffer available / visible
   vk::BufferMemoryBarrier bufMemBarrier;
   bufMemBarrier.srcAccessMask = vk::AccessFlagBits::eTransferWrite;
   bufMemBarrier.dstAccessMask = vk::AccessFlagBits::eUniformRead | vk::AccessFlagBits::eShaderRead;
   bufMemBarrier.buffer = dataBuffer;
   bufMemBarrier.offset = dataBufferOffsets[2];
   bufMemBarrier.size = sizeof( Tools::UniformBufferObject );

   for( size_t i = 0; i < cmdBuffers.size(); i++ ) {
       //begin command buffer

       cmdBuffers[i].pipelineBarrier(
           vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eHost, //srcPipelineStage
           vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eTransfer, //dstPipelineStage
           (vk::DependencyFlagBits) 0,
           nullptr, //memBarrier
           bufMemBarrierStaging,
           nullptr //imgBarrier
       );
       vk::BufferCopy copyRegion; //filled appropriate
       cmdBuffers[i].copyBuffer( uniformStagingBuffer, dataBuffer, copyRegion );

       cmdBuffers[i].pipelineBarrier(
           vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eTransfer, //srcPipelineStage
           vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eVertexShader, //dstPipelineStage
           (vk::DependencyFlagBits) 0,
           nullptr, //memBarrier
           bufMemBarrier,
           nullptr //imgBarrier
       );
       //renderpass stuff and drawing etc.
   }
   ```

   with

   ```
   namespace Tools {
     struct UniformBufferObject {
       glm::mat4 model;
       glm::mat4 view;
       glm::mat4 proj;
     };
   };
   vk::Buffer uniformStagingBuffer;
   vk::DeviceMemory uniformStagingMemory;
   //dataBuffer also contains the vertex and index data, is device local
   vk::Buffer dataBuffer;
   vk::DeviceMemory dataBufferMemory;
   vk::vector<vk::DeviceSize> dataBufferOffsets;

   std::vector<vk::CommandBuffer> cmdBuffers;
   ```

   Im using `vkcpp` (https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp).

   Is the reason for this nonfluid animation missing data coherence - and did I a mistake trying to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** The problem of part 2 was a missing syncronisation; the staging buffer was (partially) updated before it was read during rendering the frame before.  (Thanks for making clear the difference between memory being available / visible).

Comment: "*What is the difference between memory being available / being visible?*" It's not clear what you mean by "being available". "*and destroying the buffer*" Why would you destroy the buffer? What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: BTW, you do not need the first memory barrier. The memory barrier HOST_WRITE_BIT / HOST_STAGE is implicitly done by the submission of command buffer.

Comment: @NicolBolas The 1st question refers to section 6.4 of the specs, the paragraph about Memory dependencies. I couldn't see any difference. Destory a buffer means, I call `vkFreeCommandBuffers`. As this is code from a tutorial, the most easy way is chosen, not a good one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the staging-buffer memory is not host-coherent then you additionally need to `vkFlushMappedMemoryRanges` after the memcpy (the memory can remain mapped). If you don't then there is no guarantee that the data is actually visible to the gpu.

The first barrier (host to transfer) is not actually needed; there is an implicit barrier on submit.

Another issue I see is that you have a single staging buffer which means that you need to wait for the previous frame to finish before you can upload new data.

If the mention of "destroying" means that you allocate per frame ... First you have to wait on destruction until all submitted command buffers using are done, second don't do that. GPU-side allocation is expensive, instead prefer allocating once and using a ring buffer.

Answer (score 0):

ad 1.

*Available* and *visible* are two halves of a memory dependency. Pretty much both has to happen for it to be a valid memory dependency.

You could view it as a sequence of state:

Resource is writen by `src` → made available by `src` → made visible to `dst` → used by `dst`.

The purpose for it is the coherency of the caches. The specification tries to avoid that word "cache" to be more abstract.

You are in charge of the making available and visible. Operations that can do some of that are Barriers, events, coherent mapped memory or `flush` and `invalidate` and some others...

AFAIK there is a synchronization spec rewrite planned and the nomenclature may change.